# How to compute the estimator $\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}$

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval

In a question it is asked to compute the estimator $\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}$ and thus compute the confidence interval for a given set of data. I've already found the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\sigma}$ but I'm confused here as I dont understand the difference between $\hat{\sigma}$ and $\sigma$ and also what $\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}$ represents. Also the probability function is a log normal distribution of
$f(x) = \frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{ln(x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

I've found $\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln{x_i}}}$

All the question provided was the pdf.

Comment: Please elaborate more on $\sigma^2$, I bet there must be a note regarding the definition of $\sigma^2$ in the question statement.....

Comment: @Rowing0914 all the question provided was the pdf

Comment: What's the source/book of the question?

Comment: @smaillis, sorry but at least to me it is not self-explanatory so that could you put the link to your PDF or the source of this question??